# Unable to execute the maven command by using the sh file in docker image

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am using the sh file which contains all the maven configuration, secret keys, maven command and all, I I want to execute this sh file from inside the Dockerfile so that when I run the container sh file will execute.

this is how my Docker file looks like:

```
#using alpine jdk
FROM somewhere.docker.hub/build/alpine:latest AS fetch

#MVN as build tool
FROM somewhere.docker.hub/build/maven:3.5.3-jdk-8 AS build

#Settings.xml for downloading dependencies from nexus repository
ARG MVN_SETTINGS=settings.xml

#Defining the current working repository
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


#Coping the pom.xml into working directory
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app

COPY ${MVN_SETTINGS} /usr/src/app/settings.xml

# Download the package and make it cached in docker image
#RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve


#Coping the source code into the working repository
COPY  . /usr/src/app


#Run the sh file
#RUN chmod a+x /usr/src/app/DockerTest.sh

# Not using the full path of DockerTest.sh file because it is already in the work directory as defined above
RUN chmod a+x DockerTest.sh
```

DockerTest.sh file looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn clean install
mvn test
```

when I create the docker image and run the image, it shows this error.
I have tried lots of things it is still not working, it shows this error

No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Are you sure you don't execute `mvn` without any arguments, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you **cannot** combine two Docker images by using multiple `FROM` lines one after another. The reason it's even possible to specify more than one is to enable [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Second, if you're not using this line:

```
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve
```

you may as well comment this one too:

```
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
```

since your POM will be copied along with the rest of the source code.

Third, judging from your Dockerfile, you have several `settings.xml` files in your working directory and you want to choose one base on a build argument. However, if you have say `settings.xml` and `settings.prod.xml` and you set `MVN_SETTINGS` to `settings.prod.xml`, then `/usr/src/app/settings.xml` will be overwritten by this line:

```
COPY  . /usr/src/app
```

with `settings.xml`.

Fourth, `mvn clean install` [runs tests as well](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), there is no need to do `mvn test` separately.

Finally, for the issue you have noticed. I'm not sure what you expect to happen when you run the image, but you did not specify any entrypoint or command to be run in your Dockerfile, so your image inherits the default one from its base. Now assuming that by `somewhere.docker.hub/build/maven:3.5.3-jdk-8` you actually mean `docker.io/library/maven:3.5.3-jdk-8` then the command is `mvn` and the entrypoint is `/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh` (see `Dockerfile` for a slightly newer image [here](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/26ba49149787c85b9c51222b47c00879b2a0afde/openjdk-8/Dockerfile)).

With all that said, assuming you want to run `DockerTest.sh` when your image is run, your `Dockerfile` should look like this:

```
FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8
ARG MVN_SETTINGS=settings.xml
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
COPY ${MVN_SETTINGS} settings.xml
RUN chmod a+x DockerTest.sh
CMD ./DockerTest.sh
```

Also, if you actually want to use your `settings.xml` during build you need to change your `DockerTest.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn --settings /usr/src/app/settings.xml clean install
```

You could also remove unnecessary copying the same file twice by doing:

```
FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8
ARG MVN_SETTINGS=/usr/src/app/settings.xml
ENV MVN_SETTINGS=${MVN_SETTINGS}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN chmod a+x DockerTest.sh
CMD ./DockerTest.sh
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn --settings "$MVN_SETTINGS" clean install
```

Comment: `RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve` 
when I uncomment this line to use the dependency from cache, and run the docker image it downloads the dependency, again and again, every time I run the docker file, I want it to get the dependency from docker and do not download when I run the image again.

Comment: That's because copying new pom.xml invalidates all the layers below.

Comment: Now I am copying all the specific folder also not overriding pom file, still it is downloading dependency again and again- please help.

Comment: please see the updated question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115576/unable-to-cache-maven-dependency-in-docker-image