# Unable to cache maven dependency in docker image

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, devops, docker-maven-plugin

I am using the sh file which contains all the maven configuration, secret keys, maven command. when I run the container it downloads the dependency again and again everytime, it is unable to cache the dependency.

Here is how my Dockerfile looks like :

```
#MVN as build tool
FROM docker.hub.com/maven:3.5.3-jdk-8

#Settings.xml for downloading dependencies from nexus repository
ARG MVN_SETTINGS=settings.xml

#Maven project pom
ARG MVN_POM=pom.xml

#Defining the current working repository
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


#Coping the settings.xml into working directory
COPY ${MVN_SETTINGS} settings.xml

#Coping the pom.xml into working directory
COPY ${MVN_POM} pom.xml

#Download the package and make it cached in docker image
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:resolve


#Coping the source code into working repository
COPY  src .

COPY  Test.sh .

#Execute permission
RUN chmod a+x Test.sh

#Entry point for docker container
CMD ./Test.sh
```

Here is the Test.sh file

```
#!bin/bash
mvn test -DtestSuite=src/test/resources/suites/Suite.xml
```

When I create the docker image and run the container it downloads the dependency, again and again, every time I run it.

Comment: How are you building and running the image?  Is the `mvn dependency:resolve` step getting re-run on every build, or does `mvn test` download dependencies again?

Comment: Steps getting rerun on every build and downloading the dependency again everytime

Comment: Would this due to the fact the `mvn dependency` plugin does not fully download all the dependencies? if yes, you might have a look at this other SO question [Maven/Docker: cache all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52892488/9164010) (which mentions a plugin that seems to behave better than `mvn dependency:go-offline`)

Comment: Please look at my solution at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71066133/418599 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible - at least using "regular" Docker and Dockerfile - see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593135/does-putting-arg-at-top-of-dockerfile-prevent-layer-re-use) for an explanation.

You can however achieve the desired effect using an [experimental Dockefile syntax](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/dockerfile) to [enable caching](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) for `RUN` statement:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
FROM docker.hub.com/maven:3.5.3-jdk-8

ARG MVN_SETTINGS=settings.xml
ARG MVN_POM=pom.xml

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ${MVN_SETTINGS} settings.xml
COPY ${MVN_POM} pom.xml
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:resolve

COPY src .
COPY Test.sh .
RUN chmod a+x Test.sh
CMD ./Test.sh
```

The above Dockerfile will enable caching of `/root/.m2` directory. The command will still run every time, but the dependencies will not be redownloaded. That said, this Dockerfile will not work with "regular" Docker. It requires [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

I would also recommend using [BuildX plugin](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) and building the image with `docker buildx build` to allow for easy switching between build engines without setting and unsetting an environmental variable.