# How to cache all maven dependencies before building an Docker Image?

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, maven-plugin, quarkus

I'm trying to improve the building time of a project Image (Quarkus + Maven + JDK17),
by using Docker's caching feature.
I found some stuff online but only got me this far on the solution, here's the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
#1st STAGE
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

RUN mvn -f pom.xml package

#2nd STAGE
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17-jre
WORKDIR /app
CMD "java" "-jar" "/app/application.jar"
```

So basically I'm copying only the `pom.xml` from the project, trying to download all the dependencies before building the project and only after this I'll build the project, but the problem I'm facing is:
Whenever I change anything on my source code that is located under `src`, it still downloads some dependencies, in which I suppose should have been downloaded on the `RUN mvn dependency:go-offline` step. There are other steps here that are necessary and I'm missing?

Notes:
1 - I have the `go-offline` plugin added to the `pom.xml` with `3.1.2` version.
2 - It seem to only download dependencies from the framework I'm using (Quarkus).

I've already tried adding:

`RUN mvn dependency:resolve`

`RUN mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`

Also tried the `build-kit` from docker.

There's also this one:
[Unable to cache maven dependency in docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115576/unable-to-cache-maven-dependency-in-docker-image)

All together, and all separated but no success.

A simple reproducible example would be to create a new Quarkus project, use this Dockerfile and add a simple `hello world`, build, and then after changing it, no dependencies should be downloaded, since no new dependencies were added since the last build.

PS.: One thing that I've noticed, is that if I try to run
`mvn package -o` on my machine I'll get the following error:

```java
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.1.2 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

But as you can imagine, I've already run the 'package' command several times, so I guess the dependencies should be under '.m2' repository, why the error?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at `docker-buildkit` (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57781332/4216641) by [Farzad Vertigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3939318/farzad-vertigo) for details). --- If we want to execute this step in a CI/CD pipeline, I suggest taking a look at the caching options of the CI/CD solution used. Unfortunately, they are not always perfect.

Comment: I forgot to add, but I've already been trough docker-buildkit and also no success. I'll update the question, but thank you anyway.